# Wordpress error log - client denied by server configuration

Tags: wordpress, brute-force

My friend told me this morning that her website looks like it was hacked and some ads put on it. I asked her to send me the logs. There doesn't seem to be anything jumping out, until I get to the error log. Here I get 151 lines that state:

```
[Sun Oct 30 16:04:30 2016] [error] [client 78.181.104.152] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/carolas.nl/httpdocs/wp-login.php, referer: http://carolas.nl/wp-login.php
```

I checked the geolocation for the IP and it seems to be coming from Turkey. To me, it looks like a brute force attack that was unfortunately a success but can someone confirm that? I couldn't find that IP as blacklisted anywhere so it would be a bit strange for a random Turkish person attacking a website in Holland.

I suppose my question is am I correct in saying that it was a brute force, what's the best way to prevent it and what else can I check in the logs that might give me some more information?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.designwall.com/blog/track-record-logged-user-activity-wordpress/     check this but I am not sure it is the answer of your question.